# Qt QGL includes not found

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed the last QT Creator, running a gived example code, but i get
`error: 'QGLFormat' file not found` and
`error: 'QGLWidget' file not found`

My pro file looks like

```
GLEW_PATH = ../ext/glew-1.9.0
GLM_PATH  = ../ext/glm-0.9.4.1

TEMPLATE  = app
TARGET    = myfilename

LIBS     += -Wl,-rpath $${GLEW_PATH}/lib -L$${GLEW_PATH}/lib
LIBS     += -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -lm
INCLUDEPATH  += $${GLEW_PATH}/include  $${GLM_PATH}

SOURCES   = main.cpp viewer.cpp
HEADERS   = viewer.h

CONFIG   += qt opengl warn_on thread uic4 release
QT       += core gui opengl xml widgets
```

The errors happen here in my only header `viewer.h`, but others includes look fine

```
// GLEW lib: needs to be included first!!
#include <GL/glew.h> 

// OpenGL library 
#include <GL/gl.h>

// OpenGL Utility library
#include <GL/glu.h>

// OpenGL Mathematics
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <QGLFormat>  //Error here
#include <QGLWidget>  //and here
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
...
```

with a main quite simple

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <QString>
#include "viewer.h"

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  QApplication application(argc,argv);

  Viewer viewer;
  viewer.show();

  return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you done due dilligence? That is, check where the missing files are on your system, and compare that with the include path you set when you compile. If you haven't done that then do it now. Either way report back on what you find.

Comment: Did you press "Run qmake" (under "Build") the last time you changed the .pro makefile? I can't spot anything wrong by looking at your files.

Comment: Qmake is part of the Qt creator Build operation, so i think yes. I did it alone, the qmake goes well, but the make then fail

Comment: I saw here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglformat.html they were deprecated in QT5. I have Qt6. May have they been removed ?

Comment: I finally installed QT5 and it worked